# Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with message 'The EntityManager is closed

Tags: doctrine-orm, entitymanager

How to pass doctrine entity manager to some class constructor?

For example, i set-up and create entity manager `$em` in file _someAction.php.
In the same file i instantiate the class, and pass entity manager to the constructor, but em does not work in the class. I am getting

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with message 'The EntityManager is closed.'

## class dealErrCl

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use someNamespace\LogErr;

class dealErrCl {
 private $em; //entity manager to save error to the entity

public function __construct( \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em ) {
        $this->em = $em; 
}

public function flush($errArr) {

    $this->le = new LogErr(); 
    
    if( isset($errArr['title']) ) {
        $this->le->setTitle($errArr['title']); 
    } 
/*...*/

    $this->em->persist($this->le);
    $this->em->flush();
```

}

## _someAction.php

```
include DbCon.php; // configures doctrine and creates $em. If i use this em in this file, it works, but if i tryt to pass it to some class constructor, it gives Fatal error.

use LogBundle\Components\ErrC\dealErrCl; 
$dealErrIn = new dealErrCl($em);
```

If i use this $em in  _someAction.php file, it works, but if i tryt to pass it to some dealErrCl constructor, it gives Fatal error.

Comment: Seems the solutions is here: https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/tag/doctrineormexception-the-entitymanager-is-closed/

Comment: My errors was `desc` keyord, which is reserved. and should not be used as a fiedl name.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is an error during the flush, which closes the entity manager.

There maybe many possible errors:

1) setting null on non-null field

2) using reserved keywords for field name
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

POSTGRE reserved words :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

MYSQL reserved words:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Thus better always enclose all flush, inside a try-catch block.